# MEAN Stack Application throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN so I try to be as precise as possible with this. I followed a tutorial step by step for a small MEAN Stack application. Everything works fine so far except of editing and saving when viewing in AngularJS (tested PUT and DELTE with Restful client and it works fine).

According to the error message I receive, the error seems to lay in one of my Controllers with the save function.

The error I receive is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
at /Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/cms/controllers/surveysController.js:29:15
```

Bellow is my controller

```
require('../models/survey');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Survey = mongoose.model("Survey");

exports.post = function(req, res){
var survey = new Survey(req.body);
survey.save();
res.jsonp(survey);
};

exports.get = function(req, res){
    Survey.find().exec(function(err, surveys) {
        res.jsonp(surveys);
    });
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
    Survey.load(req.params.surveysId, function(err, survey){
        res.jsonp(survey);
    });
};

exports.put = function(req, res){
    Survey.load(req.params.surveysId, function(err, survey){

        survey = _.extend(survey, req.body);

        survey.save(function(err){
            res.jsonp(survey);
        });
    });
};

exports.delete = function(req, res){
    Survey.load(req.params.surveysId, function(err, survey){
        survey.remove(function(err){
            res.jsonp(survey);
        });
    });
};
```

There seems to be a problem with the section bellow, to be on point with ".save(function(err)". I followed the tutorial step by step and I can't figure what the problem is here. As mentioned before, it works fine in RESTClient.

```
exports.put = function(req, res){
    Survey.load(req.params.surveysId, function(err, survey){

        survey = _.extend(survey, req.body);

        survey.save(function(err){
            res.jsonp(survey);
        });
    });
};
```

As Requested the Schema bellow

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SurveySchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    von: Date,
    titel: String,
    beschreibung: String
});

SurveySchema.statics = {
    load: function(id, cb){
        this.findOne({_id : id}).exec(cb);
    }
};

mongoose.model('Survey', SurveySchema);
```

Comment: Don't try to build the whole stack in one go and see if it works. Use postman to test your api first. Once that is working you know its an angularjs problem

Comment: where is the schema @jake? Can you please give me the link of the tutorial.

Comment: @Gandalf the white It's a video to brain tutorial on my hard drive so there isn't a link I can provide. I did update my initial post and included the Schema

Comment: @JoeLloyd I didn't, I practiced multiple times because I had problems with basic terminal commands and cohesions. Thanks for the advice concerning postman